# Error committed neglecting a term

Tags: real-analysis, percentages

I have such an expression: $$ |G|=\frac{R_2A}{R_2+(1+A)R_1}$$
(this is the gain function of an inverting op amp, but it's not important, I think..)
It's noticeable that: $$|G_{\infty}|=\lim_{A\to \infty}|G|=\frac{R_2}{R_1}$$
Clearly, in real world, $A$ is big, but not infinite, so I'm wondering: what is the percent difference between $|G_{\infty}|$ (which I measure) and $|G|$ (which I should get)? I was thinking about: $$\frac{|G_{\infty}|-|G|}{|G|}\cdot 100=-\frac{R_2R_1^2+R_2^2R_1}{R_1^2R_2+R_1^2R_2A+R_1R_2^2} \cdot 100 \Rightarrow \frac{k_1}{k_1+A\cdot k_2}$$
Then, how should I proceed? I can get a percent variation at any fixed value of $A$, for every $(k_1, k_2)$ points? Is there any other extimation that exclude at least the values for $(k_1, k_2)$?

Comment: Personally, I dread treating percentages as the *number* $\alpha$ in $\alpha\%$, but be as it may, what are $k_1$ and $k_2$?

Comment: the last term (after the arrow) is representative of what is on the left of the arrow, so.. $k_1=R_2R_1^2+R_2^2R_1$, and $k_2=R_1^2R_2$

Comment: ah, ok, so no $-100$ in there, good.

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: Maybe $\frac{k_1}{k_1+k_2A}$ is more interesting to you in a form like $\frac1{1+\frac A{1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}}}$.